# Is it possible to add an icon to top tab navigator in React Native Router Flux?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I want to add an icon to every scene (tab) in the `<Tabs></Tabs>` component from `react-native-router-flux`.

I've noticed that the icons do indeed show when `tabBarPosition="bottom"`.

My code looks similar to this:

```
<Stack>
  <Tabs tabBarPosition="top">
    <Scene icon={({focused}) => (
      <Icon name="star" />
    )} hideNavBar />
    <Scene icon={({focused}) => (
      <Icon name="audiotrack" />
    )} initial hideNavBar />
    <Scene icon={({focused}) => (
      <Icon name="album" />
    )} hideNavBar />
 </Tabs>
</Stack>
```

(Note that I've only included code related to my problem, nothing else)

Icons for Tab navigators with `tabBarPosition={true}` should be available in the component, as is evident in `react-navigation`'s `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` as well as the documentation of `react-native-router-flux`, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this feature is not implemented for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

yes, It worked for me by adding the following props to the tabs scene

```
<Scene
  key="mainScreen"
  tabs
  initial
  tabBarPosition='top'
  lazy
  showIcon // here
  showLabel={false} // here
>
  <Scene
    wrap={false}
    hideNavBar
    key="hey"
    component={Events}
    icon={({ focused }) => <IconContainer />}
  />
</Scene >

// IconContainer Component
const IconContainer = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',

      }}
    >
      <Icon name='name-of-the-icon' size={15} />
    </View>
  );
};
```